# How to Implement and Register to a COM Callback

Tags: c#, com, callback

I'm trying to create a COM interface that allows for Callback from the COM to the calling code. I can't seem to find any proper explanation for this in C#.

I got a normal COM interface working, but I don't know how to properly register and set up the callback part.

I can't find any information on how to do this properly in C#, as most google search terms I can come up with that include "com" only lead to .com sites, and don't include actual com interfaces when talking about callbacks and events, they only include the default non-com ones. Any help would be appreciated, even if it's just pointing out to a source where I can find better, more helpful information.

My Callback Interface looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ComAdapter
{
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
    [Guid("7f176b75-7b66-463a-94ab-493943792f88")]
    public interface INet40Callback
    {
        [PreserveSig]
        void Callback(string data);
    }
}
```

The Callback class I tried to look like this:

```
using net40lib;
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ComAdapter
{
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(INet40Callback))]
    [Guid("023e4ad9-77d1-461e-af89-4cfc2b53959c")]
    public class Net40Callback : INet40CallbackRegistration
    {
        [ComVisible(false)]
        public delegate void MyCallbackDelegate(string data);

        public event MyCallbackDelegate Callback;

        public INet40Callback callbackObject;

        public Net40Callback()
        {
            Net40Class.Instance.VersionSent += Instance_VersionSent;
        }

        void Instance_VersionSent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (callbackObject != null)
            {
                callbackObject.Callback("blah");
            }

            if (Callback != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Instance_VersionSent Sending Callback");
                Callback("blah");
            }
        }

        public void RegisterCallback(INet40Callback reg)
        {
            if (reg is INet40Callback)
            {
                callbackObject = reg as INet40Callback;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The calling application so far looks like this:

```
using ComAdapter;
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace net20lib
{
    class Net40Callback : INet40Callback
    {
        [PreserveSig] 
        public void Callback(string data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Callback Called with data {0}", data);
        }
    }
}
```

Registration:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ComAdapter
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("3b2ab267-9e9a-47be-ab0a-f55db10a971e")]
    public interface INet40CallbackRegistration
    {
        void RegisterCallback(INet40Callback callback);
    }
}
```

The Call from the Test Class:
The implementation of the interface:

```
internal class Net40Callback : INet40Callback
{
  [PreserveSig]
  public void Callback(string data)
  {
      Console.WriteLine("Callback Called with data {0}", data);
  }
}
```

The Code for registration:

```
INet40Callback callback = new Net40Callback();

Type myCallbackType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("ComAdapter.Net40Callback");
object myCallbackInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(myCallbackType);
INet40CallbackRegistration registration = (INet40CallbackRegistration)myCallbackInstance;
registration.RegisterCallback(callback);
```

Comment: So, what exactly is not working? Does your client COM test app call `RegisterCallback` at all? I don't see that in the C# code you listed. Note, `ComSourceInterfaces` is used when you want to exposes a C# class events to COM (via `IConnectionPointContainer` interface, which the Interop Runtime implicitly implements for you).

Comment: Thanks. I updated the info, and also updated the code to what I tried right now. to represent what my code currently looks like (which should be closer to working, but still doesn't.
I create the callback class and register, with the interface. What my problem seems to be right now is that it tells me the interface is incorrect, I get an InvalidCastException with "HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)". The exception text is in german so it won't help much.

Comment: I looked up the exception in english, it should be:

Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'ComAdapter.INet40Callback'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

Comment: The [PreserveSig] attribute is evil and has to be removed.  An IDispatch method must always be able to return an error code.  You get the E_NOINTERFACE error because your Net40Callback test class is not [ComVisible].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really shouldn't be testing C# COM server from C# COM client, this is not how it works when it's called from unmanaged code. Then you wouldn't need to keep a reference to `INet40Callback`, the `event` declarations should be enough for a COM client to hook up events via `IConnectionPointContainer` (using the type library generated by RegAsm). Unless you really want to support both options.

Anyway, to make your current code work, try adding `[ComVisible(true)]` to `Net40Callback` and `[ComImport]` to `INet40Callback`:

```
[ComImport]
[ComVisible(true)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
[Guid("7f176b75-7b66-463a-94ab-493943792f88")]
public interface INet40Callback
{
    // ..
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]]
[ComDefaultInterface(typeof(INet40Callback))]
internal class Net40Callback : INet40Callback
{
    // ...
}
```

**Updated**, you don't need to change much on the C# side, besides removing the `public INet40Callback callbackObject` reference. However, you need an unmanaged COM client to test the events. It can be a plain C++ COM app, an ATL/MFC C++ app, a VB6 app, or even an HTML App (.HTA file with an `<object>` tag inside). Here's an example of the latter (untested). Copy it to `test.hta` run this file from Windows Explorer:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Managed COM Object Test</title>

    <object id="managedObject"
        classid="clsid:023e4ad9-77d1-461e-af89-4cfc2b53959c"
        codebase="#version=0,0,0,0">
    </object>

    <script for="managedObject" event="Callback(data)" type="text/javascript">
        output.innerText = "Callback(" + data + ") fired";
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="output">&nbsp;</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Adding ComVisible to the interal Net40Callback that is located in the client still generates the same exception. 
For the other information I'll have to look up how to do that.

Comment: @private_meta, is that `registration.RegisterCallback` what's giving you such error? I just amended the code, try it that way.

Comment: I updated my code with your information, and it seems to work. the Callback method gets called by the COM Interface. Thanks for that. I will try to get the first part of your answer working, but I don't quite understand it. How should I do that? Obviously I haven't worked with COM a lot.

Comment: If I remove the callbackObject, then my RegisterCallback is more or less meaningless, how else do I register for callbacks/events then? I can't seem to see how to do that.

Comment: @private_meta, your unmanaged COM client can still do explicit binding like `RegisterCallback`, if you have control over the unmanaged code. If you don't, and you still want to understand how COM events are sourced and handled, read up on `IConnectionPoint`, `IConnectionPointContainer` and how they're related to the managed code. The ".NET and COM: The Complete Interoperability Guide" book by Adam Nathan is highly recommended.

Comment: I'll stay with RegisterCallback for now as this should work for me at the moment. If problems arise, I'll refer back to your book recommendation and the IConnectPoint and IConnectPointContainer Interfaces, Thank you!