# Issue With WPF WebBrowser Control When Emulation > IE7

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I have a C#/WPF application that uses a WebBrowser control that presents a website as it's primary interface (for a kiosk). The website can call a C# method via javascript for some native processing. Everything works fine until I set the 'FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION' above IE7 (using the code below). When I do the javascript call to the native method does not get called unless I run the website from 'http://localhost' which works fine.

I'm assuming this is a security issue. I've messed with all of the security settings in IE (including setting the site as a 'Trusted Site'), but I can't seem to get it working.

Coding I'm using the set the emulation:

```
private void SetBrowserCompatibilityMode()
    {
        // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330720(v=vs.85).aspx

        // FeatureControl settings are per-process
        var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName( Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName );

        if ( String.Compare( fileName, "devenv.exe", true ) == 0 ) // make sure we're not running inside Visual Studio
            return;

        using ( var key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey( @"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION",
            RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree ) )
        {
            // Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE10 Standards mode.
            UInt32 mode = 11000; // 11000 = IE11, 10000 = IE10, 9000 = IE9, 8000 = IE8, 7000 = IE7; 
            key.SetValue( fileName, mode, RegistryValueKind.DWord );
        }

        using ( var key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey( @"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_ZONE_ELEVATION",
            RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree ) )
        {
            // disable zone elevation prevention
            UInt32 mode = 0;
            key.SetValue( fileName, mode, RegistryValueKind.DWord );
        }

        using ( var key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey( @"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BLOCK_LMZ_SCRIPT",
            RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree ) )
        {
            // enable <scripts> in local machine zone
            UInt32 mode = 0;
            key.SetValue( fileName, mode, RegistryValueKind.DWord );
        }

        using ( var key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey( @"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_NINPUT_LEGACYMODE",
            RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree ) )
        {
            // disable Legacy Input Model
            UInt32 mode = 0;
            key.SetValue( fileName, mode, RegistryValueKind.DWord );
        }

    }
```

Comment: You might want to show how you're exactly you're calling that C# method via javascript.

Comment: FYI, it's not a C# WebBrowser. It's the WPF WebBrowser control.

Comment: Some questions for you:
1) how's the server side code implemented? Webforms, ASP.NET MVC, WCF
2) how's the JavaScript code implemented? Pure JavaScript, JQuery, ASP.NET AJAX Toolkit?
3) Can you show some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable `FEATURE_LOCALMACHINE_LOCKDOWN`, `FEATURE_BLOCK_LMZ_SCRIPT`, `FEATURE_BLOCK_LMZ_OBJECT` features. You can adapt the working C# code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30364129/1768303). Alternatively, I believe you can use ["Mark of Web"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/23/understanding-local-machine-zone-lockdown-restricted-this-webpage-from-running-scripts-or-activex-controls.aspx) to make your scripts run again.

Answer (score 0):

try one of these:
1- run your program as administrator.
2- check that your JavaScript is compatible with the version you are emulating as some JavaScript code run on IE7 but not above.

Update:
This is how I set the emulation, please note that this code will not work if you do not run it as administrator:

```
    private static void SetIEVersioneKeyforWebBrowserControl(string appName, int ieval)
    {
        RegistryKey Regkey = null;
        try
        {
            Regkey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", true);

            //If the path is not correct or 
            //If user't have priviledges to access registry 
            if (Regkey == null)
            {
                _logger.Error("Application FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION Failed - Registry key Not found");
                return;
            }

            string FindAppkey = Convert.ToString(Regkey.GetValue(appName));

            //Check if key is already present 
            if (FindAppkey == ieval.ToString())
            {
                _logger.Debug("Application FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION already set to " + ieval);
                Regkey.Close();
                return;
            }

            //If key is not present or different from desired, add/modify the key , key value 
            Regkey.SetValue(appName, unchecked((int)ieval), RegistryValueKind.DWord);

            //check for the key after adding 
            FindAppkey = Convert.ToString(Regkey.GetValue(appName));

            if (FindAppkey == ieval.ToString())
            {
                _logger.Info("Application FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION changed to " + ieval + "; changes will be visible at application restart");
            }
            else
            {
                _logger.Error("Application FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION setting failed; current value is  " + ieval);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error("Application FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION setting failed; " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            //Close the Registry 
            if (Regkey != null) Regkey.Close();
        }
    }
```

and to use the function:

```
        var targetApplication = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName + ".exe";
        int ie_emulation = 9000;
```

Comment: Tried running as administrator, no luck (but good suggestion). As far as 2 we're using jQuery 1.10 and it does work when running with the website local.

Comment: My problem is not setting the FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION mode I see that working in the registry it's communicating from javascript to a native function if FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION > IE7.