# WPF webbrowser control + suppress script error+ Allow block content

Tags: wpf, webbrowser-control

while displaying in wpf+webbrowser control, Displaying "Allow Blocked COntent" warning messages.....

```
     <input type=button
               onclick="showModalDialog('C:\\Temp\\Test1.htm');"
               value="Show Me as Modal Page." />
        <BR />
        <a href="javascript:alert('I am

 shown.')">
       I should work using href.
    </a>
    <BR />
    <a href="#" 
       onclick="javascript:alert('I am shown.')">
       I should work using onclick.
    </a>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issue With WPF WebBrowser Control When Emulation > IE7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30314106/issue-with-wpf-webbrowser-control-when-emulation-ie7)